# Xamarin Java.IO.File.ListFiles с root правами

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Дано:

1. Устройство рутовано
2. С помощью SuperSU предоставлены права приложению

Получаем:
Исключение при вызове

`Java.IO.File[] files = (new Java.IO.File("\Data\Data")).ListFiles();`

Вопрос, как получить доступ к:

1.Структуре каталогов с root правами

2.Содержимому файлов с root правами

Спасибо

Comment: какие права вы предоставили приложению при помощи SuperSU?

Comment: @ZigZag да, права `ROOT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция сканирования папки

```
private static string[] lsDir(String dirPath, bool sudo = true)
{
  List<string> item = new List<string>();
  try
  {
    using (Java.Lang.Process p = sudo ? Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new string[] { "su", "-c", "ls", "-sal", dirPath }) : Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new string[] { "ls", "-lsa", dirPath }))
    {
      try { p.Wait(); } catch { }
      try { p.WaitFor(); } catch { }
      using (BufferedReader log = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.InputStream)))
      {
        string line;
        while ((line = log.ReadLine()) != null)
          item.Add(line);
      }
    }
    return item.ToArray();
  }
  catch 
  {
  }
  return new string[0];
}
```

а теперь пропарсим

```
string[] dirs = lsDir(item.Data, false);
if (dirs.Length == 0)
  dirs = lsDir(item.Data);
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?<type>[-|d|l|b|c|p|s]{1})(?<perm>[r|w|x|-]{9}){1}[ ](?<owner>[\S]*)[ ]+(?<group>[\S]*)[ ]+(?<size>\d*)[ ]*(?<dt>[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}[ ][\d]{2}:[\d]{2})[ ](?<fn>[\S]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (string i in dirs)
{
  if (match.Groups["type"].Captures.Count != 1) continue;
  if (match.Groups["perm"].Captures.Count != 1) continue;
  if (match.Groups["owner"].Captures.Count != 1) continue;
  if (match.Groups["group"].Captures.Count != 1) continue;
  if (match.Groups["size"].Captures.Count != 1) continue; //может быть пустым ""
  if (match.Groups["dt"].Captures.Count != 1) continue;
  if (match.Groups["fn"].Captures.Count != 1) continue;
  //Все данные хранятся по Captures
  //match.Groups[key].Captures[0].Value
}
```